# Get min and max value from this array of hashes

Tags: ruby

I have an array that contains a hash in each row containing created_at and a value.  How do I get the min and max from the array for the value fields?

The array is called - `channels_counts_for_history_graph`

and

```
channels_counts_for_history_graph.max[1]
```

Gives me the max date rather than the max value?

```
[[Sun, 30 Dec 2018 15:03:55 UTC +00:00, 4305],
[Sun, 30 Dec 2018 15:05:42 UTC +00:00, 4305],
[Mon, 31 Dec 2018 09:24:06 UTC +00:00, 4306],
[Sat, 05 Jan 2019 09:04:50 UTC +00:00, 4308],
[Tue, 01 Jan 2019 11:26:04 UTC +00:00, 4306],
[Wed, 02 Jan 2019 17:24:19 UTC +00:00, 4305]]
```

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe show some sample data?

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mcve].

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with the elements you show as `Time` (or `DateTime`?) objects.  Yet, to answer the question readers must change those elements to strings and either leave them as strings or convert them to `Time` objects, both of which is a waste of time. It would have been simpler to make them, say, integers. When you give an example it's helpful to assign a variable to each input (`arr = [...]`) so that readers can refer to those variables in answers and comments without having to define them.

Comment: Also *"Gives me the max date rather than the max value?"*  what do you mean with *max date* and *max value*? A date is a value and a value could be a date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default when you sort an array sorts by the first element first.

You can reverse the array for the purposes of the sort.

```
channel_counts_for_history_graph.map(&:reverse).max[0]
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using [`Enumerable#minmax_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-minmax_by) to get the min *and* the max value in just one method call:

```
array = [['Sun, 30 Dec 2018 15:03:55 UTC +00:00', 4305],['Sun, 30 Dec 2018 15:05:42 UTC +00:00', 4305],['Mon, 31 Dec 2018 09:24:06 UTC +00:00', 4306],['Sat, 05 Jan 2019 09:04:50 UTC +00:00', 4308],['Tue, 01 Jan 2019 11:26:04 UTC +00:00', 4306],['Wed, 02 Jan 2019 17:24:19 UTC +00:00', 4305]]

array.minmax_by(&:last)
#=> [["Sun, 30 Dec 2018 15:03:55 UTC +00:00", 4305], ["Sat, 05 Jan 2019 09:04:50 UTC +00:00", 4308]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I may guess that this is what you were asking for:

```
 [{ created_at: Date.new(2017, 1, 1) }, { created_at: Date.new(2019, 1, 1) }, { created_at: Date.new(2018, 1, 1) }]
   .minmax_by { |value| value[:created_at] }
```